# Matlibplot only showing one of the plots on a stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, stacked-chart

I am trying to do a matlibplot stacked bar chart.  I am writing out two different plots, but only one of them shows.  I am not sure why that would be.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    data = {'a':['Usair', 'delta', 'american', 'airlondon', 'United','Peoples 
                 Express','Joes airline and grill'],
            'b':[9052, 9394, 9837, 8911, 10251, 8092, 512],
            'c' :[3002,8000,7600,7933, 8123, 2089,109 ]
           }
    
    df= pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    df.columns = ['airline', 'flights', 'on time']
    df['ontimepct'] = df['on time'] /df['flights']
    df

ind = pd.Series(np.arange(7))
w = 0.50


plt.bar(ind, df['ontimepct'], w, color = 'r', label= 'On Time')
plt.bar(ind + w, df['flights'], w, color = 'g', label='Flights')

plt.show
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are plotting the on time percentage, which are super small relative to the flights. For example, there are 9000 flights but the on time percentage between 0 and 1. So, they are not visible but `matplotlib` is plotting them.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = {'a': ['Usair', 'delta', 'american', 'airlondon', 'United', 'PeoplesExpress','Joes airline and grill'],
                                                'b':[9052, 9394, 9837, 8911, 10251, 8092, 512],
                                                'c': [3002, 8000, 7600, 7933, 8123, 2089, 109]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df.columns = ['airline', 'flights', 'on time']
    df['ontimepct'] = df['on time'] / df['flights']

    ind = pd.Series(np.arange(7))
    w = 0.3

    plt.bar(ind, df['on time'], w, color='r', label='On Time')
    plt.bar(ind + w, df['flights'], w, color='g', label='Flights')

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]